# Need to insert and refresh the page at submit button

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a comment section in my page.

```
<form class="reply-form" id="reply-form" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $post->ID;?>" id="postid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only control-label" for="name"></label>
                        <input id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="NAME" required="" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only control-label" for="email"></label>
                        <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-MAIL" required="" type="text" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12 mb30">
                        <label class="sr-only control-label" for="textarea"></label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" name="textarea" rows="3" placeholder="COMMENT"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default sub">Submit</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
```

This is how my insert comment function works:

```
if(isset($_POST['singlebutton'])){
$postid = $_POST["id"];
$name   =$_POST['name'];
$email  =$_POST['email'];
$comment=$_POST['textarea'];

$commentdata = array(
  'comment_post_ID' => $postid, 
  'comment_author' => $name,  
  'comment_author_email' => $email, 
  'comment_content' => $comment, 
  'comment_type' => '', 
  'comment_parent' => 0, 
  'user_id' => $current_user->ID, //passing current user ID or any predefined as per the demand
);


$comment_id = wp_new_comment( $commentdata );
}
```

Now my problem is that when i hit submit button it refreshes the page and only insert the comment in database and only in next refresh the comments are being displayed in mu page. i have tried using script for window load but that dosent seem to do the work. what can i do ?

Comment: put action in your form if the insert is in another page <form class="reply-form" id="reply-form" method="POST"> to <form class="reply-form" id="reply-form" action="insert.php" method="POST">

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form class="reply-form" id="reply-form" method="POST" action="yourclassname.php">
```

Add the action like mentioned above.....

Answer (score 0):

After the submit code redirect the page to itself.

**IN PHP**

```
header('Location: redirectpage.php');exit();
```

**In Javascript**

```
echo "<script>location.href='redirectpage.php';</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

//Just Change name To uname so ‘name’ is not available for a field name.

```
<input id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="NAME" required="" type="text">
```

To

```
<input id="name" name="uname" class="form-control" placeholder="NAME" required="" type="text">
```